# xhr.open POST is not working on IOS - Canvas to Blob script

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

**Update**
I have come to notice this is the exact part of the code not working only on IOS

```
xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
xhr.send(data);
```

### --------------------

So i have this code that works beautifully. It is designed to take a photo from the file input, resize it via canvas to blob & dataurl, and then pend it to a post "upload.php", where the modified file is then uploaded to the server. After uploading the image, the user clicks "button A" and function "upload" begins. It displays the modified image on the page and sends it over to the form for upload.

**The Issue**: It works everywhere I need it to, except on IOS. I am really not sure why, but on IOS when you click the button nothing happens. I added a function to change the page background color when clicked just to check it, and that works, but the rest of the script does not. I am lost.

I tried adding this API below the "if (canvas.toBlob)":

```
// 80x60px GIF image (color black, base64 data):
var b64Data = 'R0lGODdhUAA8AIABAAAAAP///ywAAAAAUAA8AAACS4SPqcvtD6' +
    'OctNqLs968+w+G4kiW5omm6sq27gvH8kzX9o3n+s73/g8MCofE' +
    'ovGITCqXzKbzCY1Kp9Sq9YrNarfcrvcLDovH5PKsAAA7',
imageUrl = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + b64Data,
blob = window.dataURLtoBlob && window.dataURLtoBlob(imageUrl);
```

This was referenced on [Github Canvas To Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob), but it did not do anything.

Below is the code I am using, and even further below is the "upload.php" file

```
<script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>

<label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label><br />

 <input type="file" name="file[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" /> 

<output id="filesInfo"></output>
<output id="filesInfo2"></output>

<button id="a" onclick="upload()">Button A</button>

<script>


function upload(){
    var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
    }
}



function resizeAndUpload(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {

var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.src = reader.result;
tempImg.onload = function() {

    var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 800;
    var tempW = tempImg.width;
    var tempH = tempImg.height;
    if (tempW > tempH) {
        if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
           tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
           tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
    } else {
        if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
           tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
           tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = tempW;
    canvas.height = tempH;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");









 if (canvas.toBlob) {
canvas.toBlob(
    function (blob) {
        // Do something with the blob object,
        // e.g. creating a multipart form for file uploads:
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob, file1);
        /* ... */
    },
    'image/jpeg'
);
}









    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';







    };

var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = '<img style="width: 90px;" src="' + dataURL + '" />';
                document.getElementById('filesInfo2').appendChild(div);



    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
    xhr.send(data);
  }

 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}


</script>
```

PHP file below

```
<?php


if ($_POST) {
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'jobimages/');
$img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . '55889' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
}


?>
```

Comment: Might be that IOS blocks network traffic over http? I.e. try https?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with compatibility in xhr.open and IOS safari.

**The solution:**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "upload.php";
var params = 'image=' + dataURL;
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
}
}
http.send(params);
```

**Instead of:** (which only works on desktop browsers)

```
xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
xhr.send(data);
```